# Why am I getting a page not found 404 error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a change-password and change-username system for my users, however when I try to visit the page, I get a 404 page not found

[image]

**urls.py:**

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('forget/', views.forget, name='forget'),
        path('', views.login_user, name='login'),
        path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
        path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
        path('register/', views.register_view, name='register'),
        path('edit-register/', views.edit_register_view, name='edit_register'),
        path('change-password/', views.password_change, name='password_change'),
        path('reset-password/', views.PasswordReset.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
        path('reset-password-done/', views.PasswordResetDone.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
        path('reset-password/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirm.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
        path('reset-password-complete/', views.PasswordResetComplete.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
    
    ]
```

**views.py:**

```
    def forget(request):
        msg = None
        # Get userid from session
        userid = request.session.get('userid')
        print(userid)
        # Get user object from User database
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=userid)
        if request.method == 'POST':  # check for the post request body
            form = ForgetForm(request.POST, instance=user)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                print(form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
                msg = 'user password updated'
                return redirect('/login')
            else:
                msg = 'form is not valid'
        else:
            form = SignUpForm()
    
        return render(request, 'forget.html', {'form': form, 'msg': msg})
```

**forms.py:**

```
    class forgetForm(forms.Form):
        username = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "class": "form-control"
                }
            )
        )
        password1 = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    "class": "form-control"
                }
            )
        )
        password2 = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    "class": "form-control"
                }
            )
        )
```

Let me know if further information is required.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that the user with that ID wasn't found when it executed this line.

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=userid)
```

You are getting the user ID from the stored session:

```
userid = request.session.get('userid')
```

Perhaps you haven't correctly populated the value for that. Make sure that it was correctly [saved for the current session ID](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved). You can verify this by checking the `sessionid` in the cookies (it should be visible in the request headers section in the browser) and looking at its values in the table `django_session` in your database. The key `userid` must be there.

An alternative is to try accessing instead `request.user` specifically `request.user.id`. Note that `request.user` is also populated [based on session data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware).

If everything above fails, verify the user ID really exists in your user database.